# Converting sniff scapy packet into pcap format to pass in named pipe into Wireshark

Tags: python, scapy, pcap, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I have been buidling a packet sniffer in Python using scapy. I am trying to integrate Wireshark in the sniffer via a named pipe as specified on the Wireshark documentation https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes.md. The problem is the example uses pcap data read from a file with open() function and when I try to pass in scapy packet converted like `bytes(sniffed_packet[0])`, despite looking similar to when open() is used on a pcap file, an error occurs on Wireshark saying the data is on proper pcap or pcapng format. I have tried a bunch of ideas and nothing yet. Does anyone know how I could easily convert the sniffed scapy packet into the proper pcap format to send it through the named pipe?

Ive tried converting the packet into bytes and using a ByteIO buffer with wrpcap functions, problem is that the function closes the file descriptor on completion so even if I could use that function to format pcap data in memory, I am not able to read it due to the close IO descriptor.